# How to force a queue to run synchronously for tests?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, observer-pattern

We have an app that sends messages, and request specs that ensure that the messages are sent.

We are adding a queueing system for the messages. Each message is stored in the db, and then later processed and deleted. The records are de-queued asynchronously in another process. So the specs now fail.

What is a good way to automatically process the queue for the specs?

One approach would be to add an observer to the queue that automatically processes each message as it is queued. But I'm not sure if it makes sense to do it that way, especially since it is only for tests.

What is a good way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you have spec that creates a message and sends it, then somehow verifies that it was sent. Now you are changing the app to queue messages and send them later. Where you had previously had one feature (send a message), now you have two features (1. queue a message; 2. send a message).

I'd say the specs should test those features separately, i.e., one spec that verifies that newly created messages are queued, and another spec that verifies that any queued message is sent. That will make the specs much easier to implement, and the specs will better reflect the behavior of the application.

Comment: We have request specs that make a request to our app, and an expectation that the app makes a request to our messaging service (Pusher). I do have unit tests for the queue, but want to preserve our end-to-end request specs.

Comment: Let's say you write an end-to-end spec that handles queueing and sending, and you get the spec to pass. What does that mean? If the asynchronous process fails in production, the request will still complete normally, correct? The message sending portion of the app is no longer a dependency for the message queueing portion - the two features work independently. Testing them together would only produce a false sense of security.

Comment: That's true, but the message sending is not the main feature of the app. It's more of a side effect. The sending runs using Resque Scheduler, which is not part of the tests. If it fails then the messages will not go out. We do not have tests to make sure Resque Scheduler is running. We have unit tests on the model that Resque calls. These tests show that show that if the Scheduler is running, then the messages go out.